# My First WCF Service and I'm Stuck

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

It took a good bit of trial and error, but I was finally able to host my WCF Service in IIS.

I can browse to the WSDL no problem, and see all of the different methods/attributes.

Now what?  I need to use my service inside of another Web App.  How do I do that?

I was able to use svcutil.exe to generate the *.cs and output.config files, add that to my web app, and add a reference to System.ServiceModel  That worked fine.

BUT, I need to figure out how to use my service hosted in IIS.

In my web app I've added a web reference to the WSDL, but I can't figure out how to expose the methods/attributes.

I'm not ruling out the possibility that there's a better way to do this...so I'm open to suggestions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the client project and click "Add Service Reference".  Then put in the address of your WCF service and it will create the proxies and plumbing for you.

Comment: Thanks D, that was it.  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as it'll let me.
Do I still need the System.ServiceModel reference?  It's leftover from when I was using the *.cs and output.config files.

Comment: Yes you will still need that reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Service Reference to your service. By doing this you don't need the svcutil. 
Or you can use the .cs that svcutil generated for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730144.aspx

Simply you have to use the class on your .cs file. Istantiate it and call wcf methods...